# Got an error reading communication packets

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to figure out the reason why I keep occasionally getting the following errors accessing MySQL from Python:

```
 2018-02-13T10:28:22.4616239Z 137675 [Note] Aborted connection 137675 to
 db: 'unconnected' user: 'username' host: '132.20.21.10' (Got an
 error reading communication packets)
```

Possible causes, according to the documentation:

- The client program did not call mysql_close() before exiting.

Shouldn't be the case since we have a finally: code block that executes close().

- The client had been sleeping more than wait_timeout or interactive_timeout seconds without issuing any requests to the server. See Section 5.1.5, “Server System Variables”.

Definitely not.

- The client program ended abruptly in the middle of a data transfer.

Definitely not.

- The max_allowed_packet variable value is too small or queries require more memory than you have allocated for mysqld. See Section B.5.2.9, “Packet Too Large”.

Definitely not.

- A problem with the thread library that causes interrupts on reads.

Has anyone had any issues using python MySQLdb and more specifically mysqlclient https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient ?

- Badly configured TCP/IP. Faulty Ethernets, hubs, switches, cables, and so forth. This can be diagnosed properly only by replacing hardware.
  Use of Ethernet protocol with Linux, both half and full duplex.

Shouldn't be the case since it is working most of the time.

If you have any thoughts, they would be greatly appreciated!

**** EDIT ***

The finally code looks like this:

```
 def execute(self, query):
    try:
        connection = self.pool.connect()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        return data
    finally:
        connection.close()
    return data
```

The pool was initialised as follows:

```
import MySQLdb
import sqlalchemy.pool as pool

    def __init__(self, config, logging_name=None):
            def getconn():
                c = MySQLdb.connect(host=config.host, port=int(config.port), user=config.user,password=config.password,charset='UTF8')
                return c  
            self.pool = pool.QueuePool(getconn, logging_name=logging_name)
```

Comment: Please post your finally: code block so we can see your sequence.

Comment: Thank you very much @WilsonHauck for your help! This database is used by two applications, and only the python application is causing an error. I added the finally code to the original post.

Comment: What is the BYTE count expected to be gathered with FETCHALL?  Are U willing to supply any of the other information requested on first Apr 2 request?  Rather than asking 10 more questions to get the information we need to consider possible causes.

Comment: This link   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-close.html  may have a clue in the User Comments (near the end).  Is your connection.close() equivalent to mysql_close() - since the problem is only occasional, this may be irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks @WilsonHauck, the connection_close() is not actually equivalent to the mysql_close(). It uses an sqlalchemy pool - I will check how it behaves without it and update this thread.

Comment: Could you tell us the BYTE count expected to be gathered with FETCHALL? Are U willing to supply any of the other information requested on first Apr 2 request? Rather than asking 10 more questions to get the information we need to consider possible causes.  Thanks